# No Json deserializer found for type List[(java.util.UUID, String, String, String, Int, Int, Int, Int, java.sql.Timestamp)]

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

My scala skill is lacking but I've been wrestling with this. But I'm having a problem serializing and deserializing JSON. I've googled and searched StackOverflow but unfortunately I cannot piece it together.

So this is my last resort..

My model is:

```
package models

import java.util.UUID
import java.sql.Timestamp


import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.json._


import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import Database.threadLocalSession

case class User(
  id:UUID,
  username: String,
  password: String,
  email: String,
  comment_score_down: Int,
  comment_score_up: Int,
  post_score_down: Int,
  post_score_up: Int,
  created_on: Timestamp)

object Users extends
  Table[(UUID, String, String, String, Int, Int, Int, Int, Timestamp)]("users"){

  implicit object UserFormat extends Format[User] {

    implicit object UUIDFormatter extends Format[UUID] {
      def reads(s: JsString): UUID = java.util.UUID.fromString(s.toString)
      def writes(uuid: UUID) = JsString(uuid.toString)
    }

    implicit object TimestampFormatter extends Format[Timestamp] {
      def reads(s: JsValue): Timestamp = new Timestamp(s.toString.toLong)
      def writes(timestamp: Timestamp) = JsString(timestamp.toString)
    }


    def reads(json: JsValue): User = User(
        (json \ "id").as[UUID],
        (json \ "username").as[String],
        (json \ "password").as[String],
        (json \ "email").as[String],
        (json \ "comment_score_down").as[Int],
        (json \ "comment_score_up").as[Int],
        (json \ "post_score_down").as[Int],
        (json \ "post_score_up").as[Int],
        (json \ "created_on").as[Timestamp]
      )
     def writes(u: User): JsValue = JsObject(List(
         "id" -> JsString(u.id.toString),
         "username" -> JsString(u.username),
         "password" -> JsString(u.password),
         "email" -> JsString(u.email),
         "comment_score_down" -> JsString(u.comment_score_down.toString),
         "comment_score_up" -> JsString(u.comment_score_up.toString),
         "post_score_down" -> JsString(u.post_score_down.toString),
         "post_score_up" -> JsString(u.post_score_up.toString),
         "created_on" -> JsString(u.created_on.toString)
       ))
  }


  def id = column[UUID]("ID", O.PrimaryKey) // This is the primary key column
  def username = column[String]("username")
  def password = column[String]("password")
  def email = column[String]("email")
  def comment_score_down = column[Int]("comment_score_down")
  def comment_score_up = column[Int]("comment_score_up")
  def post_score_down = column[Int]("post_score_down")
  def post_score_up = column[Int]("post_score_up")
  def created_on = column[Timestamp]("created_on")

  def * = id ~ username ~ password ~ email ~ comment_score_down ~
    comment_score_up ~ post_score_down ~ post_score_up ~ created_on

}
```

My controller:

```
  def getUsers = Action {
    val json = database withSession {
      val users = for (u <- Users) yield u.*
      Json.toJson(users.list)
    }
    Ok(json).as(JSON)

  }
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kay, I got it sweet.

Made some edit to my model:

```
case class User(
  id:UUID,
  username: String,
  password: String,
  email: String,
  comment_score_down: Option[Int],
  comment_score_up: Option[Int],
  post_score_down: Option[Int],
  post_score_up: Option[Int],
  created_on: Timestamp)

object Users extends Table[User]("users"){
```

I also changed my object signature so that it can return type User instead of just User's parameters. And I just have to append <> (User, User.unapply _) to my projection method (the *).

But in my controller:

I just needed:

```
  implicit object UserWrites extends Writes[User] {

    def writes(u: User) = Json.obj(
         "id" -> JsString(u.id.toString),
         "username" -> JsString(u.username),
         "password" -> JsString(u.password),
         "email" -> JsString(u.email),
         "comment_score_down" -> JsNumber(u.comment_score_down.getOrElse(0).toInt),
         "comment_score_up" -> JsNumber(u.comment_score_up.getOrElse(0).toInt),
         "post_score_down" -> JsNumber(u.post_score_down.getOrElse(0).toInt),
         "post_score_up" -> JsNumber(u.post_score_up.getOrElse(0).toInt),
         "created_on" -> JsString(u.created_on.toString)
    ) 


  }
```

as member of the controller class.

So now my controller action is just:

```
  def getUsers = Action {

    val json = database withSession {
      val users = for (u <- Users) yield u
      Json.toJson(users.list)
    }
    Ok(json).as(JSON)
  }
```

Edit:

Alternatively, I've moved the getUsers code to my model as a findAll method and also moved my writable to there too. I didn't like the data logic being in the controller...

So in my controller I only have a method/action:

```
  def getUsers = Action {
    Ok(Users.findAll).as(JSON)
  }
```

My model now looks like:

```
package models

import java.util.UUID
import java.sql.Timestamp


import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.json._


import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import Database.threadLocalSession

case class User(
  id:UUID,
  username: String,
  password: String,
  email: String,
  comment_score_down: Option[Int],
  comment_score_up: Option[Int],
  post_score_down: Option[Int],
  post_score_up: Option[Int],
  created_on: Timestamp)

object Users extends Table[User]("users") {

  lazy val database = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource())

  def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey) // This is the primary key column
  def username = column[String]("username")
  def password = column[String]("password")
  def email = column[String]("email")
  def comment_score_down = column[Option[Int]]("comment_score_down")
  def comment_score_up = column[Option[Int]]("comment_score_up")
  def post_score_down = column[Option[Int]]("post_score_down")
  def post_score_up = column[Option[Int]]("post_score_up")
  def created_on = column[Timestamp]("created_on")

  implicit object UserWrites extends Writes[User] {

    def writes(u: User) = Json.obj(
         "id" -> JsString(u.id.toString),
         "username" -> JsString(u.username),
         "password" -> JsString(u.password),
         "email" -> JsString(u.email),
         "comment_score_down" -> JsNumber(u.comment_score_down.getOrElse(0).toInt),
         "comment_score_up" -> JsNumber(u.comment_score_up.getOrElse(0).toInt),
         "post_score_down" -> JsNumber(u.post_score_down.getOrElse(0).toInt),
         "post_score_up" -> JsNumber(u.post_score_up.getOrElse(0).toInt),
         "created_on" -> JsString(u.created_on.toString)
    )
  }

  def * = id ~ username ~ password ~ email ~ comment_score_down ~
    comment_score_up ~ post_score_down ~ post_score_up ~ created_on <>
    (User, User.unapply _)

  def findByPK(pk: UUID) =
    for (entity <- Users if entity.id === pk) yield entity

  def findAll = database withSession {
      val users = for (u <- Users) yield u
      Json.toJson(users.list)
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your error has to do with your writes method. You have implemented a deserializer for User, but there isn't one implemented for a list of Users. The best advice I can provide is to create a writes method with the parameter type of List[User].

Comment: If there is a deserializer for type `T`, then play will also know how to deserialize `List[T]`.